# Converting 8 bits to a byte for amplitude modulation in Java

Tags: java, amplitude, modulation

So I am writing a program in Java that does amplitude demodulation. I am reading in a sine wave value by value and determining whether I have a '1' or a '0'. For now I am saving them as chars, but am open to suggestions. I know the number of samples per bit, so determining the bit is not an issue.

I can't figure out a way to convert every set of 8 bits in to a byte, so I can then decode the final array of bytes using UTF-8. Is there an effective way of doing that?

Comment: Byte.parseByte might be useful for you - set the radix to 2.

Comment: Don't you mean "bits per sample" Having more than one sample per bit is ambitious.

Comment: Why not read 8 bits at a time as almost every kind of real device uses 8 bit bytes already.

Comment: Thanks, Zyga, this is pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: Peter Lawrey, I did mean bits per sample, although it doesn't matter as you would just get the inverse, which is still a valid value, just less that 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, from the [Byte Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#Byte%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String myBitString = "10101010";
int radixTwo = 2;
byte myByteValue = Byte.parseByte(myBitString, radixTwo)
```

Obviously you can add the byte values to a `byte[]` array and then use a loop afterwards to display / decode them.

Answer (score 0):

what could be helpful is a conversion method...

```
public static byte toByte(boolean[] bits){
    assert bits.length == 8;
    int tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i ++){
        if(bits[0] ){
            tmp = tmp + (2^i);
        }
    }
    return (byte)(tmp)
}
```